# Getting more out of less?

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

So, I know this is a highly debated question... Okay so, can you use an Induction Motor to run two modified alternators at the same time, with one of them running the Electromagnets in the Induction motor and the other generating into something else. Will this create an excess of energy?

I know the name of this has already been asked but I'm wondering specifically about the above section.

Comment: I just want to point out that the concept of violating energy conservation is not "highly debated." It is overwhelmingly accepted in the scientific community that creating "free energy" is impossible. While consensus does not imply truth, in this case it may as well, since the consensus has overwhelming mathematical and experimental support.

Answer (score 3):

You know, electromagnetic and mechanical forces, disregarding any kind drag forces, are conservative, which means that you cannot create more energy that which you initially or progressively may introduce.

Hence, any possible configuration tou could figure involving rails, paths, merry-go-rounds, gears, masses, magnets, coils, etc., will never bring out more energy than all the electrical or mechanical energy than any battery or induced currents or elevated masses could deliver.

Unless you are planning to make some chemical/fision reaction, you do not have any choice of creating energy from masses, coils, magnets and batteries.